Is it possible to find 3 pairwise independent events in a space of six points?
I'm having trouble with exercise 4.6 in Billingsley, I can't seem to find 3 pairwise independent events (excluding the trivial events, the empty set and whole space) in a space of six equally likely points. I've tried 2 subsets of size 3 and 1 subset of size 1 with a common point but then the subsets of size 3 are not independent: $$\frac{3}{6}\frac{3}{6}=\frac{1}{4}\neq \frac{1}{6}.$$

This is not clear.  Please state the relevant problem in full.

You can not find... but that is more a fault of how the numbers line up than anything else and a matter of elementary number theory than to do with probability.

@lulu Rephrased... consider the uniform distribution over ${1,2,\dots,6}$.  Can you find three events $A,B,C$ over this space such that none are trivial and such that $A,B,C$ are all pairwise independent?

Suppose the probabilities are $\frac{a}{6},\frac{b}{6}$ and $\frac{c}{6}$ respectively with none of $a,b,c$ equal to zero and none of $a,b,c$ equal to $6$.
It follows that $a$ can have either a factor of $2$... or a factor of $3$... or neither.  It can not have both a factor of $2$ and $3$.  Similarly for $b,c$.
For these to be pairwise independent we would require each of $\frac{ab}{36},\frac{ac}{36},\frac{bc}{36}$ to correspond to probabilities of simple events in the space and thus could simplify to fractions whose denominator is $6$.
We would require then that $ab$ is a multiple of $6$ to have this fraction $\frac{ab}{36}$ simplify and thus without loss of generality $a$ must be a multiple of $2$ (and not a multiple of 3) and $b$ a multiple of $3$ (and not a multiple of 2).  Similarly $ac$ must be a multiple of six and so $c$ must be a multiple of $3$... but then $bc$ is not a multiple of $2$ and so $\frac{bc}{36}$ can not simplify to have a $6$ in the denominator... a contradiction.
